# C program using a wrapper libtorch c++ library not linking

Tags: c++, c, linker, linker-errors, libtorch

I'm trying to make a libtorch c++ library to use it in a C program, exporting library functions with `extern "C"`. The library seems to compile and link correctly. But the main executable doesn't link.

I have copied all `libtorch/lib/*` files to `/lib/`.

The compiler says a lot of undefined reference to libtorch functions.

Here is a minimal example. The Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wshadow -O3 -pthread -I./
CFLAGS2 = -fPIC -Wall -O3 -pthread -I./
LDLIBS = -lm

all: libnet test

libnet: 
    g++ -shared -o ./libnet.so ./libnet.cpp $(CFLAGS2) \
      -I../../libtorch/include/ \
      -I../../libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -L/lib \
      $(LDLIBS) -ltorch

test: 
    gcc -o ./test.exe ./test.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -ltorch ./libnet.so
```

The C main program test.c:

```
#include <libnet.h>

int main() {
  void* lstm = create_lstm(2, 64, 256, 1, 60);
}
```

The C header file libnet.h:

```
void* create_lstm(int layers, int hidden, int nbinputs, int outputs, int batchsize);
```

The library libnet.cpp:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>

using namespace torch;

struct LSTM_Model : torch::nn::Module {
    torch::nn::LSTM lstm{ nullptr };
    torch::nn::Linear linear{ nullptr };
    torch::optim::Adam* opt{ nullptr };
    uint64_t _batchsize;
    uint64_t _hidden;

    LSTM_Model(uint64_t layers, uint64_t hidden, uint64_t inputs,
               uint64_t outputs, uint64_t batchsize) {
        lstm = register_module("lstm", torch::nn::LSTM(
                   torch::nn::LSTMOptions(inputs, hidden)
                   .num_layers(layers)));
        linear = register_module("linear", torch::nn::Linear(
                   hidden, outputs));
    _batchsize = batchsize;
    _hidden = hidden;
    }

    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x) {
        auto lstm1 = lstm->forward(x.view({ x.size(0), _batchsize, -1 })); 
        auto out = linear->forward(
                  std::get<0>(lstm1)
                  .view({ _batchsize, x.size(0), _hidden }));
        return out; 
    }
};

extern "C" void* create_lstm(int layers, int hidden, int nbinputs,
                             int outputs, int batchsize) {
  LSTM_Model* model = new LSTM_Model(layers, hidden, nbinputs, outputs, batchsize);
    model->opt = new torch::optim::Adam(model->parameters(),
                       torch::optim::AdamOptions(2e-4).
                         betas(std::make_tuple(0.5, 0.5)));
  return (void*)model;
}
```

Here are the undefined reference errors, it is written in french:

```
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « vtable for torch::optim::Optimizer »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::to(c10::Device, c10::ScalarType, bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::LSTMOptions::LSTMOptions(long, long) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « c10::detail::torchInternalAssertFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*, char const*) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::LSTMImpl::LSTMImpl(torch::nn::LSTMOptions const&) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::train(bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::LinearOptions::LinearOptions(long, long) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « typeinfo for torch::nn::Module »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::is_serializable() const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::pretty_print(std::ostream&) const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::zero_grad(bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « vtable for torch::nn::Module »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « vtable for torch::optim::AdamOptions »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::optim::OptimizerParamGroup::options() const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « typeinfo for torch::nn::LinearImpl »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::optim::AdamOptions::AdamOptions(double) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « c10::UndefinedTensorImpl::_singleton »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::LinearImpl::LinearImpl(torch::nn::LinearOptions const&) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::clone(std::optional<c10::Device> const&) const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « vtable for torch::optim::Adam »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::to(c10::ScalarType, bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::parameters(bool) const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::optim::OptimizerParamGroup::has_options() const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::is_training() const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::to(c10::Device, bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::optim::OptimizerParamGroup::params() const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::optim::Optimizer::add_param_group(torch::optim::OptimizerParamGroup const&) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::load(torch::serialize::InputArchive&) »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::save(torch::serialize::OutputArchive&) const »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::Module() »
/usr/bin/ld : ./libnet.so : référence indéfinie vers « torch::nn::Module::clone_(torch::nn::Module&, std::optional<c10::Device> const&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:14 : test] Erreur 1
```

Comment: Put `-ltorch` after `libnet.so` on the recipe for `main`. This is a common gotcha.

Comment: Put `-ltorch` after `./libnet.so` on the command line for the test target. If that happens to fix it then [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) seems like a good dupe target.

Comment: I just tried it, and it doesn't work, still undefined references.

Comment: What are the errors? Is it a name mangling issue of trying to mix C and C++?

Comment: Use `g++` to do the linking, and compile the `main()` function in a C++ file.

Comment: I need to use the library in a C program, so I export the functions with  `extern "C"`. It doesn't seems to be a mangling issue.

Comment: @Retired Ninja, I have edited my question to add the linker errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have downloaded the libtorch CPU-only version, the problem is solved by using `-ltorch_cpu` instead of `-ltorch`, despite the file `/lib/libtorch.so` exists.